# How to remove null data from JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting the Hbase data and trying to do a spark job on it. My table has around 70k rows and each row has a column '**type**', which can have the values:**post,comment or reply**. Based on the type, I want to take out different Pair RDDs like shown below(for post).

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, FlumePost> postPairRDD = hBaseRDD.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, ImmutableBytesWritable, FlumePost>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, FlumePost> call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> arg0)
                        throws Exception {
                    FlumePost flumePost = new FlumePost();
                    ImmutableBytesWritable key = arg0._1;
                    Result result = arg0._2;
                    String type = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("t")));
                    if (type.equals("post")) {
                        return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, FlumePost>(key, flumePost);
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }

                }

            }).distinct();
```

Problem here is, For all the rows with type other than **post** I have to send null value which is undesirable. And iteration goes on for 70k times for all the three types, wasting the cycles. So my first question is:

1) What is the efficient way to do this?

So now after getting 70k results I put the `distinct()` method to remove the duplication of null values. So I end up having one null value object in it. I expect 20327 results but I get 20328.

2) Is there a way to remove this null entry from the pair RDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filter` operation on the RDD.

Simply call:

```
.filter(new Function<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, FlumePost>, Boolean>() {
   @Override
   public Boolean call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, FlumePost> v1) throws Exception {
       return v1 != null;
   }
})
```

before calling `distinct()` to filter out the `null`s.

Comment: Thanks Tzach :) Could you please answer my first question as well? Should I use SQLContext to get different types or the way I am doing is fine?

Comment: I don't think there's a serious performance issue with your implementation. Yes, you can convert this code to DataFrames and perform this using SQL and UDFs, but I'm not sure how much you'll gain performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Tzach. :)